# How can I run PhotoShop CS5 in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, photoshop

I have seen that many articles showing that Photoshop cs5,4 can be run in Ubuntu through Wine. I want to get the Photoshop for ubuntu.

Does someone know what I should do for now because I cannot find any assistance.

I have a portable version of Photoshop which work fine on Windows. I have not tried (Wine is still downloading).

Does someone have any idea how to use Photoshop on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to run Photoshop natively on Ubuntu.

You can either use wine to run it in a windows environment. (Haven't tried CS5 so I'm not sure if you have to do some tricks to make it work.)

The other way to do it is to run it in a virtual windows environment. I have Windows 7 set up as a virtual machine where I run visual studio and photoshop etc.
I did find [this blog post](http://blog.coderjobs.net/2013/01/23/how-to-use-photoshop-in-ubuntu/) where Photoshop is set up in a virtual environment but behaves (sort of) as a native application.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it under Wine.
If you don't know how to install wine here.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

Alternativity, You can use GIMP which it is free and it is a very good alternative to photoshop.
If you don't know how to install GIMP here.

13.04

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

12.10 and below

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Hope this help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I run CS2 using wine and it works just fine. I also checked the wine website and it seems that CS5 and 6 work with wine. When you view the installer (.exe), you will need to right click on the file and select 'Run using wine' and it will run the installer. When it has finished, you can click on the ubuntu logo and search for photoshop.

It now should be installed and work fine.

Post back with results please.

Comment: The OP states that the Portable version is being used therefore there is no installer.exe.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that the portable versions did not have an installer .exe.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter same problem to execute my portable photoshop in ubuntu. You can use GIMP because it has same feature of photoshop but if you prefer to use adobe products you must install virtual machine like me. In order to use my portable softwares I install windows xp to my virtual machine and it works fine.